# What happens if I upgrade Fedora?

Tags: fedora, upgrade, software-updates

I want to upgrade my Fedora 24 to version 25.

Will I lose all my configuration of the applications? For example  `emacs` configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upgrade process won't touch anything in your home directory, such as your emacs preferences.

Neither will you lose any system-wide configuration information:

> Most configuration files are stored in `/etc`. If there are any updates to them and you touched some of those files before, RPM creates new files with either `.rpmnew` suffix (the new default config file), or `.rpmsave` suffix (your old config file backed up).

However, be careful, because core pieces of software may change, and the new software might not read the old configuration files.  As always, make sure you have a backup of any data you can't afford to lose:

> Back up your important data. Every system change is potentially risky, be prepared. In case you update your workstation, it is also wise to download a Workstation Live image and make sure your hardware (graphics card, wifi, etc) works well with the latest kernel and drivers.

Quotes from [Fedora's official upgrade instructions](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade).